# OSX glassfish crashes with malloc in netbeans

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, glassfish, malloc

Has anyone else seen this error (or some variation of it)?

> java(575,0x1086b4000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10869fa71:
>   pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I get this when starting glassfish (or tomcat) from netbeans 7.2 in OSX (10.8.2).

I'm using java 1.7 update 7 (happens with update 4 as well).

Comment: I restarted netbeans several times as well as the computer. Also tried reinstalling the jdk and repaired disk permissions.

Comment: JVM's are really sensitive to bad RAM. You might want to try this. http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: Not a memory error. I get this frequently. Java 7U9-10 (10 is in beta).
Running through Eclipse.